# Get object in HTML centered but scalable to fit any screen

Tags: html, css

He there,

I am trying to get my HTML:

```
    <div class="centered">  
        <div class="container">
            <table border="0">
                <tr> <!--tablerow-->
                    <td >
                        <div align="center">    
                            <a href="./page_construction.html">
                            <img 
                                src="./img/index_left.png"
                                >   
                        </div>
                    </td>   
                    <td >
                        <div align="center">    
                            <a href="./page_appDev.html">
                            <img 
                                src="./img/index_center.png"
                                >   
                        </div>
                    </td>   
                    <td >
                        <div align="center">
                            <a href="./page_construction.html">                         
                            <img 
                                src="./img/index_right.png"
                                >   
                        </div>
                    </td>   
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

To fit into the centre of the page. The page constist of nothing else but this.
I did a bit of css and this is how I achieved that:

```
.container{

    margin:auto;
}

.centered {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

But the problam is, that I cannot change the size of overall div. It is always the same size. On any screen. Also on phone screens, going way out off bounds.

Can anyone tell me what is the best way to achieve the dynamic size but keep everything in the center of the page?

Thank you:)

Comment: In general you can achieve what you call "dynamic sizing" and scalability to any screen with the term we call "responsive design". There are front-end frameworks that come with predefined CSS classes (like [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/)) and that will help you a lot to center things and be scalable in any device.

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox can do your required job without facing issue i hope.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="centered">
    <div class="container">
      <table border="0">
        <tr>
          <!--tablerow-->
          <td>
            <div align="center">
              <a href="./page_construction.html">
                <img src="./img/index_left.png">
              </a>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div align="center">
              <a href="./page_appDev.html">
                <img src="./img/index_center.png">
              </a>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div align="center">
              <a href="./page_construction.html">
                <img src="./img/index_right.png">
              </a>
            </div>
          </td>
          <tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

give `.centered` what you desire it to look. the positioning is now taken care by wrapper.

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: which div?? can you replicate your problem in codepen or fiddle or maybe a screenshot

Comment: sorry. the table. it is too big in size. and I cannot adjust its size. It just wont affect it.. maybe I am doing it wrong I am a noob hjere :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have nothing else on the page except this, one would assume that the parent of the .centered element is the <body>

In order for it to be centered in the middle of the **Screen / Page**, first set it's parent element (in this case, the body) to take up the full size of the screen:

```
body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

After this, you could use **position: absolute** or **display: flex**:

```
/* centering with position absolute */
body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}

.centered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

/* centering with display flex */
body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do three steps:

1- Download twitter bootstrap from https://getbootstrap.com/.

2- Include the necessary files into you html in the following way:

```
     <head> 
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="location of bootstrap.min.css">
     </head>
    <body>
    ....
        <script src="location of jQuery"></script>
        <script src="location bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 </body
```

3- There are bootstrap classes `container` and `container-fluid` which make your site fit into any screen size. You may use one of these classes(according to your requirement) on the outer most div.

Now at all the places where you have used aligne="center" instead use bootstrap class as `class="text-center"`